# migrated MVC 3 to MVC 4, ASP.NET forms login not working for old accounts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, migration, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I'm in the process of migrating my MVC 3 application to MVC 4, and I am noticing that all the existing users' passwords are now not valid.

I'm using the standard ASP.NET membership schema with all the normal tables (like table `aspnet_Membership`)

Is there anything I can do to get all the passwords to work w/o having them all be reset?

The way I migrated over was I created a new MVC 4 project and copied all the files over.

#### EDIT

So, I did a little more digging and I found that the MVC4 application is not using the default `aspnet_<TableName>` table names.  It created its own tables that do not have the `aspnet_` prefix.  So now my database has an Applications, Memberships, Profiles, Roles, Users, and UsersInRoles tables, in addition to all the standard tables.  I never noticed that those tables were created, because I have similar tables already in existance in the same DB.  They just blended in!

My new question is, how do I use the existing tables for the application?  I've converted several projects like this, and I've never had to specify the specific tables to use for the asp.net membership tracking.

Here is my Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.csdl|res://*/Entities.ssdl|res://*/Entities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=db;persist security info=True;user id=dbguy;password=PPPPassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Server=tcp:database.windows.net,1433;Database=db;User ID=dbguy;Password='PPPassword';Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is it running on a different server?

Comment: Both versions are run locally on my computer (localhost)

Comment: Did you add the proper connection string?

Comment: Yes. If I create a new user with the second system (MVC4) I can log in with that username on that system but not the first system (MVC3). I also checked and the db has records for the new users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts of your `web.config` that affect this.

The first is the `passwordFormat` attribute on your membership configuration element. This can be one of `Clear` OR `Encrypted` OR `Hashed`. If you have no value set, the default is `Hashed`. I've listed this for the sake of completeness, but kind of expect that you will have already checked this as the obvious config area.

The second config to look at is the `machineKey` element. If you happened to have selected the `passwordFormat` as encrypted, then ASP.net membership will use your `machineKey` to encrypt/decrypt it. The `machineKey` is used to perform the encryption of the password. For multiple separate websites to share credential information they need to have the same `machineKey` set. In your case, you may likely have no `machineKey` defined in one or both websites and may or may not have them on separate physical machines (or rather server instances).

- [Nice Overview or membership passwordFormat configuration attribute](http://www.qualitydata.com/learn/asp-net-membership-provider-password-format)

Ideally, you will have specified a machineKey on the old MVC3 app web.config which you can copy-paste over to the new web.config. If you didn't do that, you will need to jump through some hoops to try and recover the auto generated one. I've included

- [Use Reflection to Recover Auto Generated MachineKey](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/how_to_read_auto_generated_machinekey)

Your end goal will be to have the new project using the same passwordFormat and machineKey as your old project (even if the machineKey was autogenerated because you didn't specify one explicitly in the web.config)

### EDIT - more info

Looking at the web/config provided in your question edit, look at the setting under `<system.web>` called `<profile>`, `<membership>`, `<roleManager>` *(and optionally `<sessionState>`)*. These sections tell your web project which providers to use for your website. However, the 'Default' series of providers will make some decisions on your behalf to allow the website to run on SQL Server, Azure, SQL Server CE, etc... changing its implementation behind the scenes. You will want to set an explicit provider for each of these to match your old ASP.net application. Without seeing your old web.config I'd hazard a guess that you are using the SqlProviders found in the System.Web.Profile/System.Web.Security namespaces.

So try something like this: *(check your old web.config as well to see if there is a different provider `type` for each of these config elements)*

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" /* Your other settings here */ />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

To be honest, I've never used those 'Universal Providers' yet as most of my work is using Sql Server. So if you want more information you might read up on the Universal Providers for ASP.net starting with  this [introduction blog post from Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the informaiton. I have set both projects up as `passwordFormat="Hashed"`, and I have not specified a `machineKey` in either web.config. Does the `machineKey` affect hashed passwords?

Comment: I found out what the problem is, but I have a new question.  I edited the OP for reference

Comment: @joe_coolish can you post your membership config from your web.config. If you update any of your dependencies via nuget, post the exact versions (MVC4, Also Are you using entity framework? If so please post the exact version for entity framework as well.) It sounds like you might be using a different membership provider (such as maybe the new EntityFramework membership provider)

Comment: I just added the whole web.conf.  From what I could tell, there weren't that many differences between this one and the one from MVC3?  At least as far as I could tell